# opengl lnk 2019 only one function not found

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

i have seen this error a lot in the setup of opengl, but now that it is working, there is this error now. all the rest is working just this and glClearColor isnt
i think that all the commands in gl.h and glew.h might not be working i havent tested yet, and yes they are added to the project as they should be, the libraries are loading well, but i just cant call functions from them. i was using glut and glew before with no problem, what might have happened in here?

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<chrono>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define WIDTH 320
#define HEIGHT 200

struct key {

};

GLFWwindow* window;
GLFWmonitor* monitor;
bool running = 1, windowed;
std::map<int, key> keyMap;


void update(){}



void input(){}



void draw(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

int main() {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    if (!glfwInit()) fprintf(stderr, "opengl error\n");
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "end", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {std::cout << "window error\n" << std::endl; glfwTerminate();}
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();

    while (running)
    {
        update();
        input();
        draw();
    }


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();


}
```

the errors are just these:

```
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl draw(void)" (?draw@@YAXXZ)
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: (1) `wglGetProcAddress` you need to link with the library `Opengl32.lib` see __Requirements__ section here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress  (2) _"... 'MSVCRT' conflicts with..."_ your application is building with one runtime support library type and one or more of the libraries you are using has been build with another.  This will cause unexpected runtime errors the suggest fix just stops linking with all runtime libraries and will give you missing externals you need to instead match the runtime support library type.

Comment: oh thank you, it actually helped me with founding another solution to the problem, i had my `Gl.h` and `Glu.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\gl` then i just moved to the glew headers folder and it is now working again, thank you anyways.